# batch renaming multiple file names

Tags: batch-file, dos

I'd like to rename specific image names from *_PolishedChrome.jpg to be *-pch.jpg. I tried a bunch of different ways, included the rename DOS command, but cannot find the right way to do it. The files are in a folder on my desktop and they are all .jpg images.
There are multiple files with the last part of the image name.

Example: rename 3-04012C_PolishedChrome.jpg to be 3-04012C-pch.jpg

I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what you are looking for (just place it in the same folder as the jpgs and run):

Remember to make a backup of your files before running this, as it does move files on the disk. It could be done with rename, but that is more effort, as I'd have to parse out the file name.

Also note that running this twice will re-rename your files, so it can only really be run once within a folder... that can be changed, but this is more of a starting point.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /r %%i in (*.jpg) do (
set str=%%i
set str=!str:_PolishedChrome.jpg=!-pch.jpg!!
move %%i !str!
)
```

### DEBUG version - prints out a log.txt to see what went wrong.

```
@echo off 
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /r %%i in (*.jpg) do (
set str=%%i
set str=!str:_PolishedChrome.jpg=!-pch.jpg!!
move %%i !str!
@echo move %%i !str! >> log.txt
)
```

Comment: Hmm for some reason that is not working... I made a text file pasted it in and renamed it to a .bat file and ran it and it said the syntax was incorrect. Is there another way I should be doing it? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Amanda I'm not sure why you would be getting that error. Here is what I did. I have a folder with several images all named the same way. Then I made a batch file (like you described), placed it in that folder, ran it, and it renames all the files. How did you execute the file?

Comment: @Amanda try running the debug version I just added, and tell me what shows up in log.txt

Comment: thank you for helping me! It actually ended up working when I removed the "/r" part... definitely a time-saver!! :)

Comment: Awesome. Glad it worked. Remember to 'Accept' the answer if it solved your question. :)